# Настройка параметров графа Graphviz python для отображения дружеских связей

Tags: python, графы, graphviz

Настройки примерно следующие:

```
node_attr = {
            'shape': 'egg',
            'align': 'left',
            'fontsize': '20',
            'ranksep': '0.1',
            'height': '0.2'
    }

dot = Graph(node_attr=node_attr, comment='Friends', format='png', engine='sfdp')

dot.attr(size='10,10!')
dot.render('test-output/process.png', view=True)
```

Вот, что выходит. Не очень наглядно...[image: Пример графа]

Какие настройки использовать для лучшей наглядности? Может поменять engine и что-то еще?